# Crystal Reports Shared Variable Shows 0 in Main report

Tags: crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I am having an issue with displaying a shared variable from subreport on main report. I declared a shared vaiable in subreport as

**Shared NumberVar avalue ;
avalue :=Count ({ActivityReport2.IPD})**

It shows a value of 14 in the subreport.

and in main report it is referenced as

**Shared NumberVar avalue;
avalue;**

When I try to use it in the Main report it just shows value = 0.00. 
Please help :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, could you fix it? I try to show a subrepot shared variable on the pagefooter and it shows zero, I guess the pagefooter loads before the subreport :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you try doing like this:

```
Shared NumberVar avalue :=Count ({ActivityReport2.IPD})
```

Instead of declaring and then using the same.
And use in the main report as:

```
Shared NumberVar avalue;
```

Comment: Hey Iti, Thanks for the reply. I have tried this aswell but it is still not working.

Comment: I think your main report loads first and your subreport loads later and that is why value is not being used. Can do something like that this subreport loads first, and then this variable is loaded later in main report?

Comment: Not sure how I can do that. I have put the the shared variable in a section below the sub report on main report.

Answer (score 0):

Place your formula in subreport in which you have declared your shared variable and it will reflect in your main report.later you can supress your details in subreport.
I hope this will help you